# Coinbase Commerce PHP WebHook: Failed to establish a connection to the remote server

Tags: php, coinbase-api

I'm trying to check if my webhook works, and will implement it. So that I can receive notification when charge is confirmed *(charge:confirmed)*

So I created php code to check my webhook,

```
 public function payment() {
        try {
        $user_agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
        $signature = hash_hmac('sha256',  $user_agent, '<SharedScreenKeyWebhook>');

        $headerName = 'x-cc-webhook-signature';

        $is_valid = hash_equals($signature, $headerName);
        

        if($is_valid) {
            return $is_valid;
        } else {
            return http_response_code(400);
        }
    } catch (\Exception $exception) {
        http_response_code(400);
        echo 'Error occured. ' . $exception->getMessage();
    }
 }
```

if I try to access the page, it will return me something like this

[image: Status Code based on my php code]

**Status Code: 200** Means valid

This is where my Shared Secret key came from, for my webhook

[image]

However when I tested it on my end coinbase commerce by  using send test

[image: Coinbase Commerce Send Test Button]

I am getting an error.

Please take note my shared secret key already matched to my coinbase commerce account. Also I decided not to use Coinbase Commerce wrapper for laravel framework. I just want to use typical php code to implement it

Please help me out, I was able to integrate coinbase commerce on my project however, I'm having a hard time to get callback from coinbase to monitor status of payment and update my database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this,

Just in case you are here. Please create an API Endpoint on your project using `POST`

method with

`X-Cc-Webhook-Signature` equivalent to your `Shared API Secret Key`

`User-Agent` currently I'm using `weipay-webhooks` (as per documentation)

and submit your json data for checkout

On my end I used postman to test my api end point.

[image]

Your PHP Code must accept `X-Cc-Webhook-Signature` and automatically the coinbase commerce will  use your webhook link when someone purchased.